# ASP.NET Core user manager problem in setting RefreshToken via user manager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, refresh-token, usermanager

I have this web api method in ASP.NET Core:

```
        [HttpPost("Refresh")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Refresh([FromBody]TokenRefreshDto tokenRefreshDto)
        {
            var principal = _userService.GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(tokenRefreshDto.Token);
            var username = principal.Identity.Name; 

            var user = await _userService.GetUserByUserName(username);
            if (user == null || await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user,"Default","RefreshToken") != tokenRefreshDto.RefreshToken) return BadRequest();

            var newJwtToken = await _userService.GenerateJwtToken(user);

            await _userManager.RemoveAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "Default", "RefreshToken");
            var newRefreshToken = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "Default", "RefreshToken");
            await _userManager.SetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "Default", "RefreshToken", newRefreshToken);

            return new ObjectResult(new
            {
                token = newJwtToken,
                refreshToken = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "Default", "RefreshToken")
            });
        }
```

When I try to refresh the RefreshToken it gives following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type "User" cannot be tracked
        because another instance with the same key value for "Id" is already being tracked
```

My User class is derived from IdentityUser :

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public Guid? ShopId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastActive { get; set; }
        public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Which line raises the exception?

Comment: userManager.RemoveAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "Default",  "RefreshToken"

Comment: Did you found any solution? Got the same problem and don't know what I did wrong. Injection seems to be good, everything is lifetime-scoped so per request.

Comment: Ok, I was totally wrong. If this happens to you check your whole DI. I had a custom TokenIssuer that got the UserStore injected. That service was registered as a singleton and thus got the very first UserStore ever created. So check if any dependet services are registered as singleton and change them to scoped.